# Error: Relation does not exist when running Rails in production using postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.2

I'm having a problem with my application on Heroku, and in order to determine whether it is specific to my production environment or specific to Heroku itself I am running my production environment locally on my machine with rails s -e production

When I try to load my posts index, I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
                          ^
: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
```

What's weird is my posts index works fine on Heroku, as well as in development and in test. When I run bundle exec rake db:create:all I get the follow output:

```
project_development already exists
project_test already exists
project_production already exists
```

My schema is as follows:

```
create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "body"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "author_id"
  t.boolean  "published"
end
```

When I fire up rails db in the command line, I can see the table as expected when I run \dt:

```
 public | posts             | table | Thomas
```

However when I fire it up with ENV=production and run \dt I get the following:

```
Schema |       Name        | Type  | Owner  
--------+-------------------+-------+--------
public | schema_migrations | table | Thomas
```

I've tried running ENV=production rake db:schema:load and that does not solve the problem.

For reference, here is my database.yaml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_test
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `production` database created from the `database.yml` file with `rake db:create:all` is created locally on your machine, not on heroku.

Heroku automatically infers the database config for the production environment, and creates it when you run `git push heroku master` for the first time.

The error message about `posts` table not existing is because of not running migrations on heroku. Run `heroku run rake db:migrate` to apply the migrations to the production database on heroku.

Also, you don't need to have the `production` section of the `database.yml` on your local environment.

Do refer to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4 while working for the first time with heroku; it is comprehensive and very helpful.

### EDIT

The actual problem was to get the local production database to work.

Solution was to apply the migrations correctly with `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: My database works fine on Heroku. My problem is I can't get the production database running properly on my local machine.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question then. Have you run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` on the local machine?

Comment: Ah, there was my problem. I was prepending my rake db:migrate with ENV=production, rather than appending it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :-) I updated the answer to include the correct solution. Could you please mark the answer as accepted?